# Insert function script php

Tags: php, mysql

i just learned about this new insert script into my database to avoid mysql injections.. but of some reason it doesn't work... My charts name is messages and then i got id and message as the text i want to come to the database...

Here is my new code:

```
<?php
$meddelanden = $_POST['message'];
$namn = $_SESSION['user'];
include ("connect.php");
$sql = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO messages (message,namn) VALUES (?,?)');
$sql->bind_param("ss",$meddelanden,$namn);
$sql->execute(); 
$sql->close();
$con->close(); 
?>

<form action = "meddelanden.php" id = "fromen2" method = "post">
    <input type="text" name="message" id = "type" autocomplete="off" 
            placeholder="type your chat message">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Please explain what im doing wrong, i wont approve the answer if you just say what i should do instead! Thanks for any help!

Comment: Remove `i` from `$sql->bind_param("si",$meddelanden);`

Comment: what do i get then instead? cause si = string right?

Comment: One datatype should be defined for each `?` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `si` with `s` since you are binding only one string in it and no integers ( if `$meddelanden` is not an integer). Use this instead

```
 $sql->bind_param("s",$meddelanden);
```

Comment: It says that i should avoid comments like thanks but thanks dude clear explanation!

Comment: You can accept the answer or up vote in that case. :) @unknownduck

Comment: just what I did cant upvote tho says that i got too low score:/

Comment: if i got 2 strings do i just write ss + the new variable? and add (?,?) ?

Comment: You write ss and (?,?)

Comment: could you please check my new edit and tell me whats wrong now =) then i wont bother you more x)

Comment: nothing comes to my data base anymore, before i got the id and text but now when i added $name i dont get anything @CoderDude Twodee

Comment: Are you sure the database fields, datatypes, and variables are correct? @unknownduck

Comment: hmm yeah they were i found the solution seems like i couldn't set $name to $_SESSION['user']; of some reason duno why, it worked when i put it as just  some letters instead, but it is supposed to be the sessions user tho @CoderDude Twodee

Comment: Did you do `session_start()` at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

S is string, I is integer. By putting SI you are stating two variables are being passed.